# Debugging error in Rails app running on Webrick server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, webrick, ruby-debug

I am running a Rails app on the webrick server and wanted to get error messages to be displayed to me in the console. I installed the debugger `'gem install debugger'` and the installation went off without a glitch but when I restarted the server by typing in `rails s --debugger`, I got:

```
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
```

Therefore I tried installing ruby-debug gem but I got the following error:

ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/Me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***

My query is: what is going wrong with the installation? Secondly, what would be the best way for me to get error messages to be displayed to me?

Answer (score 2):

For sure I'm late but just for anyone stuck on this, I had the same problem and fixed it by adding "gem 'debugger'" to the gemfile and running bundle update